# I want to show only 71 charecter on my screen using xslt

Tags: xslt

i am using below code to display text on my screen, but i want to show max 71 charecters  only including with spece to output string. Any Idea how would i do that?

**Current Code:**

```
 <xsl:variable name="test" select="/root/item_19" />
 <xsl:for-each select="/root/item_19">
   <xsl:if test="position()=1">
     <xsl:value-of select="Additional_Claim_Info"/>                            
   </xsl:if>
     <xsl:value-of select="Additional_Claim_Info_1"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="Additional_Claim_Info_2"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="Additional_Claim_Info_3"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="Additional_Claim_Info_4"/>
   <xsl:if test="position() mod 5 = 0">
     &#160;&#160;&#160;
   </xsl:if>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

**Current OUTPUT**
PWKB3BMAC00919MD048327L     BJBPAC00919MD048327L     PKBPPC009KKJFKGJKDF

Comment: I count 64 characters as the current output, which is < 71.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a variable, get all the data in it, and then do a substring of the variable:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="output">
        <xsl:variable name="test" select="/root/item_19" />
        <xsl:for-each select="/root/item_19">
            <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                <xsl:value-of select="Additional_Claim_Info"/>                            
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="Additional_Claim_Info_1"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="Additional_Claim_Info_2"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="Additional_Claim_Info_3"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="Additional_Claim_Info_4"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() mod 5 = 0">
             &#160;&#160;&#160;
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($output, 1, 71)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score -4):

Yes. Use the 'more' program with settings to show only 71 characters.

This is not a function of XSLT.